# google docs list javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-docs-api

Hello I am new in google docs API, I want to get list of all documnets not spreadsheet using google doc API, I have got API but that gives document when you specify documentId, can anyone have idea is there way to get list of all documents created by user.

```
window.gapi.client.docs.documents.get({documentId:'123'})
```

aboe is sample code to get specific document I want list of all document.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to get a list of documents in a user's Drive? or where? It seems to me you want to use the Drive API, and add some filters to the query.

Comment: @Aerials no, I want a list of documents that users have created.

Comment: Where do you want check this?

Comment: I am working on react app where I want to show a list of documents created by the user in dropdown

Comment: Where are the users creating the "documents"? Where are they being stored?

Comment: in google docs where you can create a new document or spreadsheet but I want to list of docs created by the user in google docs

Comment: https://docs.google.com/ here where users create documents

Answer (score 1):

Those documents are stored in the user's Google Drive. You have to get their consent first.
Create a GCP project and a consent screen for users to authorize your App to access their Google Drive through the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js).

Then you can [list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) the files in their Drive.